# Save worksheet to a new workbook with the same format and name from a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to save an entire worksheet to a new workbook, to have the same format, the name of the new workbook to be based on specific cell.

I have the following code:

```
Sub cautare_copiere()

'1. declar si setez variabilele
'2. sterg rezultatele vechi
'3. cauta si lipeste intr-un nou tab

Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'de unde este informatia copiata
Dim raportsheet As Worksheet 'unde este copiata informatia
Dim salveaza As Worksheet 'unde se copiaza informatia pentru output
Dim familie As String
Dim ultimulrand As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'numaram randurile

'setez variable

Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set raportsheet = Sheet2
Set salveaza = Sheet4
familie = raportsheet.Range("B2").Value
valoare = raportsheet.Range("D2").Value
cantitate = raportsheet.Range("F2").Value


'sterge datele din tab-ul Raport
salveaza.Range("A5:L200").ClearContents 'ajustez range-ul de unde sterg datele - daca am informatie multa, il maresc
salveaza.Range("A5:L200").ClearFormats



'se duce in tab-ul Copy, cauta si copiaza
datasheet.Select
ultimulrand = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'cauta printre randuri si selecteaza informatia pe care o cautam

With datasheet
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, 5) = familie And .Cells(i, 8) <= valoare And _
                                      .Cells(i, 7) <= cantitate Then
            'Copierea unui range este relativa la rand....
            .Rows(i).Range("A1,C1,E1:H1").Copy _
                    salveaza.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        End If
    Next i
End With

'aranjeaza in ordine crescatoare, formateaza pagina si adauga anumite valori inainte de salvare
With salveaza
    .Range("A5:L200").Sort Key1:=.Range("F5"), Order1:=xlAscending 'sorteaza in coloana F in ordine crescatoare
    .Range("A2").MergeArea.Value = .Range("C5") 'adauga valoare in casuta

End With

'selecteaza casuta B2 din Raport dupa ce a terminat de copiat informatia
With raportsheet

   .Select
    .Range("B2").Select

End With

End Sub
```

It copies data from Sheet1 to Output sheet and then return to Raport sheet. I would like to save the Output sheet to a new workbook and save as B2 value from Raport sheet name.

Thank you!

Comment: Enter `[vba] copy worksheet to new workbook` into the search box. At time of writing this, 1916 results from which the first one provide a code sample that is applicable with small modifications to your case.

Comment: I wanted something into that code as I'm a newbie with VBA. Thanks for your answer. I will figure it out ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
Sub cautare_copiere()

'1. declar si setez variabilele
'2. sterg rezultatele vechi
'3. cauta si lipeste intr-un nou tab

Dim datasheet As Worksheet 'de unde este informatia copiata
Dim raportsheet As Worksheet 'unde este copiata informatia
Dim salveaza As Worksheet 'unde se copiaza informatia pentru output
Dim familie As String
Dim ultimulrand As Integer
Dim i As Integer 'numaram randurile

'setez variable

Set datasheet = Sheet1
Set raportsheet = Sheet2
Set salveaza = Sheet4
familie = raportsheet.Range("B2").Value
valoare = raportsheet.Range("D2").Value
cantitate = raportsheet.Range("F2").Value


'sterge datele din tab-ul Raport
salveaza.Range("A5:L200").ClearContents 'ajustez range-ul de unde sterg datele - daca am informatie multa, il maresc
salveaza.Range("A5:L200").ClearFormats



'se duce in tab-ul Copy, cauta si copiaza
datasheet.Select
ultimulrand = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'cauta printre randuri si selecteaza informatia pe care o cautam

With datasheet
    For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, 5) = familie And .Cells(i, 8) <= valoare And _
                                      .Cells(i, 7) <= cantitate Then
            'Copierea unui range este relativa la rand....
            .Rows(i).Range("A1,C1,E1:H1").Copy _
                    salveaza.Range("A200").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        End If
    Next i
End With

'aranjeaza in ordine crescatoare, formateaza pagina si adauga anumite valori inainte de salvare
With salveaza
    .Range("A5:L200").Sort Key1:=.Range("F5"), Order1:=xlAscending 'sorteaza in coloana F in ordine crescatoare
    .Range("A2").MergeArea.Value = .Range("C5") 'adauga valoare in casuta

End With

'selecteaza casuta B2 din Raport dupa ce a terminat de copiat informatia
With raportsheet

Dim xPath As String

xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
    raportsheet.Copy
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=xPath & "\" & .Range("B2").Value, FileFormat:=51 'Change file name to suit your needs
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False


End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but what I want is to run when I perform the search and create a new workbook with the name using the criteria from Raport worksheet B2 ....

Comment: The script does work but it saves the entire workbook as a new file not the output worksheet only. I need to save as a new workbook that contains only the Output worksheet. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreiK Hmm...ok I have mine in a for loop but it should still work. Can you try now again did a small change maybe it will help.

Comment: Your formula works perfect, but when creating a new workbook it copies the entire workbook and saves it with the name from cell B2. I have 4 worksheets on the main workbook. (1)Sheet1 (2)Raport (3)Output and (4)Data. On Raport worksheet, when I press Search button, it will copy data from Sheet1 to Output. I need only that Output worksheet to be saved to a different workbook and saved as name from cell B2 from Raport worksheet. Your code copy everything into the new workbook.

Comment: I can share this file with you, maybe it will give you a better understanding of what I need

Comment: @AndreiK Just tested it on my pc and now its working sorry did it all on my phone didn't tested it before.

Comment: now it's almost perfect :) .... I wanted to saved output worksheet, so I've changed raportsheet.Copy to salveaza.Copy. The only issue now is the file extension. it save the file without any extension....just NAME instead NAME.xls

Comment: @AndreiK are you sure? I tested it and it saved it as xslx format and opend the saved file in excel everything worked fine in my test. Can you open the file in excel? If still have problems change fileformat:=51 to fileformat:=“.xslx” or delete including comma and do & “.xslx” so basically concatenating.

Comment: Might be from me as I'm using a mac . I will test it tommorow on a windows computer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AndreiK never develop on a mac if it’s intended for Windows you’ll find yourself with unpredictable results as Mac is more limited than windows in terms of VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will install Windows & Office on a VM for this.